# Why the random code generated by this code is storing as 7 digits some times instead of 8 digits

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is generating eight digits,but while storing in db it is sometimes storing as 7 digits.the db column width is taken as int(11) and db is mysql(5.0.45)

```
srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
 $maxid = rand(0,100000000);
 $mtidno = str_pad($maxid,8);
 $shuffled = str_shuffle($mtidno);
 echo  $shuffled;
```

Comment: If leading zeroes matter, then it isn't a number: it's a string. Use `CHAR(8)` to store it.

Comment: This is not the way to generate a unique identifier, if that is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

First, by using `str_pad` like that, you are introducing spaces, which could go into the middle of your "random" number.

Change your `str_pad` call into this:

```
str_pad($maxid, 8, "0");
```

to get rid of the spaces. Note though, other questions give better ways of creating a random 8 digit number.

Then, when your shuffle result starts with `0`'s, they will drop off.

To remedy, you could use a `CHAR(8)` in your database. It will then show the leading zeroes.

Comment: Or, better yet, don't touch the way it's stored in the database and just format it for display purposes. Changing to `CHAR(8)` just doubled the storage size requirement for that column in the database.

Comment: @ColinMorelli it all depends on the use case, I'd say. If it is a number with which he wants to do math, make it an `INT`, otherwise I'd go with `CHAR`.

Comment: In my opinion the leading 0 is a problem, but even if that is corrected, the code is pure wrong.

Comment: @Amit, hard to say without knowing specs.

Comment: @Bart, I am sure the spec did not meant that space counts as a digit. The code as written would result in 8 'characters', not digits; whatever is a non digits would would be spaces; could be 1 digit and 7 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that you get even 7 digits. Won't the padding simply append spaces to the right? What happens if the rand function returns 1?

You might be getting 7 and 8 digits just by pure luck - the randomness. Try for some time and you should start seeing every combination between 1 and 8 digits.

That plus what Bart said, leading 0s would simply drop off.

Speaking of which, if you have rand, why do you need shuffle? The following should suffice.

```
srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
$maxid = rand(10000000,99999999);
echo $maxid;
```

Test code (to illustrate wrong logic)

```
srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);

for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
{
    $maxid = rand(0,100000000);
    if($maxid < 100000){
        echo  $maxid . "<br>";
        $mtidno = str_pad($maxid,8);
        $shuffled = str_shuffle($mtidno);
        echo  $shuffled . "<br>";  
    }
}
echo "done <br>";
```

See the following output, which clearly shows the spaces in there after the shuffle.

```
0
0
12207
20 21 7
82397
78 329
64086
64086
42724
4 4 2 27
21362
216 32
57983
7 3 598
```